# How to test data passed to closure, with phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a class, which generate a data object and pass it to given callable variable

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public function bar(callable $closure)
    {
        $data = $this->generateData();

        call_user_func_array($closure, compact($data));
    }

}

// example usage
$baz = new Foo()
$baz->bar(function($data) {
    var_dump($data); // I want to test $data type inside this closure
});
```

How can I test `$data` dataType pass to the anonymous function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$baz = new Foo();
$baz->bar(function($data) {
    $this->assertSame('expected', $data);
});
```

Also make sure that your closure is even called, probably by setting a variable:

```
$baz = new Foo();
$called = false;
$baz->bar(function($data) use (&$called) {
    $called = true;
    $this->assertSame('expected', $data);
});
$this->assertTrue($called);
```